# Is this a good use for javascript eval?

Tags: javascript, eval

We have a form with many question, some of which are only displayed based on dynamic logic related to other questions that is sent over in JSON.

Each question will have logic similar to, but possibly more complex than:

Display me if: `(quest1 == value1 OR quest1 == value2) AND (quest2 == value3 OR quest3 == value4)`.

Simplified JSON example:

```
[
    "AND",
    {
        "quest1": "value1,value2"
    },
    [
        "OR",
        {
            "quest2": "value3"
        },
        {
            "quest3": "value4"
        }
    ]
]
```

As the parent question values change it seems one way to determine the visibility of the child question is to parse the JSON for the given question into JS-friendly syntax like above, including the actual current values and use `eval()`. Is there a better alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your json with the dynamic logic ?

Comment: Can you create an example JSbin or the like to give us an idea of how your code works? Without further context, I'd say "Modern JS has no need for eval, just check what the previous answer is, and swap in the next question from a template or the like". There should be no need to use JSON in there at all.

Comment: I, for one, don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you please [edit] your question and show some code related to the JSON in question? I'm not sure how `eval()` would apply here at all, regardless of whether it is a good idea to use it in a general sense.

Comment: If you can trust the input 100% then I don't see a problem with using eval in this particular case. You could come up with a tree-like structure you could parse but it seems like overkill here.

Comment: That said, it's probably better to calculate that logic on the server and either send the data or not depending on the result, instead of sending all data to the client along with instructions on when to display it.

Comment: I would use a proper data structure which you can evaluate using a function rather than evaluating a string.

Comment: Just send the values you want to compare to in a json, and use a forloop to assure that they are all true. You don't need to eval.

Comment: @nnnnnn I added a representative JSON example. Its like follow-up questions, based on the logic defined for each question and the answers the user provides as they fill out the form additional questions will be displayed.

Comment: @Juhana I can't calculate the logic on the server side unfortunately, it's dependent on answers to the questions as they fill out the form, like follow-up questions. It also needs to run while offline in an app.

Comment: Well if you *already* have the logic in tree structure *then* it's more reasonable to parse the logic with a simple parser instead of eval. (It'd been different if the server returned JS code.)

Answer (score 1):

I wont give a lecture about why not to use eval.  Just never use it.

Perhaps you could represent the display logic for your question something like this.  It really depends on how complicated your logic gets and what would be a useful representation.

```
var display_logic = {"operator":"and","conditions":
    [
    {"operator":"or","conditions":
        [
        {"operator":"equals","input_id":"question1","value":"val1"},
        {"operator":"equals","input_id":"question2","value":"val2"}
        ]
    },{"operator":"equals","input_id":"question3","value":"val4"}
    ]
};
```

**Edit**: I actually prefer the format you gave so I will work with that instead.  The code below uses a recursive evaluation function to evaluate the structure to true or false.  You can then easily extend your logic operators how you want.

```
var visibility_logic = [
    "AND",
    {
        "quest1": "value1,value2"
    },
    [
        "OR",
        {
            "quest2": "value3"
        },
        {
            "quest3": "value4"
        }
    ]
];

//Interface to however you are accessing the answers
var qa_interface_func = function(question) {
    //E.g.
    //return $("#" + question).val();
    //For debugging, I will assume the answer is always "value3"
    return "value3";
};

//Recursive function which returns true or false based on the visibility logic and the current answers
function evaluateVisibility(item, qa_interface_func) {

    if (typeof item === "object") {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            //Item is an array
            //Assume index 0 is the operator and the rest are conditions
            if (item.length < 3) {
                console.err("Bad structure", item);
                return false;
            }
            var operator = item[0];
            if (operator === "AND") {
                //All conditions need to be true to evaluate to true
                for(var index=1; index<item.length; index++) {
                    if (!evaluateVisibility(item[index], qa_interface_func)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } else if (operator === "OR") {
                //1 condition needs to be true to evaluate to true
                for(var index=1; index<item.length; index++) {
                    if (evaluateVisibility(item[index], qa_interface_func)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                console.err("Unknown operator", operator);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            //Item is an object
            //All mappings must be true to evaluate to true
            for (var key in item) {
                var accepted_values = item[key].split(",");
                var current_value = qa_interface_func(key);
                if (accepted_values.indexOf(current_value) === -1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        console.err("Must be an object or an array", item);
    }
}

if (evaluateVisibility(visibility_logic, qa_interface_func)) {
    console.log("Yes, show this question");
} else {
    console.log("No, hide this question");
}
```

This code above prints out "No", but you can get it to say "Yes" if you fiddle with the logic array.

Comment: This is similar to the JSON I'm getting (I can post more when I'm home) The question is how do I evaluate it from this?

Comment: I added JSON to my original question

Comment: Ok. Yes it's very similar. You need a recursive evaluator function. I will write an example tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I have built this exact scenario. I assembled the questions and answers as a tree server-side and then load the model into the page via an Ajax call. Each Question object has the question text and an array of Answer objects, and a property (initially null) to hold any chosen answer. Each Answer object contains the answer value and a pointer to the next Question based on that answer. I use a self-referential Knockout template that displays the questions and the list of answers in a select. When an answer is chosen,  that triggers the if logic that displays the next question and possible answers- -  if: question.chosenAnswer().

The key here is to build a tree and traverse it using whatever library or framework you are using.

I am on my phone right now and will add some code when I have a real keyboard.

Answer Structure: `{ answerId, answerValue, nextQuestion }`

where answerId is a unique number/id that identifies that unique path through the tree to get to that answer.

Question Tree:

```
    {
    question: "Are there lots of questions?", // string
    chosenAnswer: null, // Answer
    answers: [
        {
            answerId: 1,
            answerValue: "Yes",
            nextQuestion: {
                question: "How many answers can there be?",
                chosenAnswer: null,
                answers: [
                    {
                        answerId: 2,
                        answerValue: "1",
                        nextQuestion: null // leaf
                    },
                    {
                        answerId: 4,
                        answerValue: "2",
                        nextQuestion: {
                            question: "How do you decide?",
                            chosenAnswer: null,
                            answers: [
                                {
                                    answerId: 5,
                                    answerValue: "Guess",
                                    nextQuestion: null // leaf
                                },
                                {
                                    answerId: 6,
                                    answerValue: "Think",
                                    nextQuestion: null // leaf
                                },
                            ]
                        }
                    },

                ]
            }
        },
        {
            answerId: 7,
            answerValue: "No" 
            nextQuestion: null // leaf
        },
    ]
}
```

You can load this via an AJAX call and if you are using jQuery for AJAX, you can get the parsed JSON in the .done(response).  If not, you can use JSON.parse().  No eval needed.  I build my knockout.js view model based on this structure.

Then it is simply a matter of using your framework (knockout, angular, etc) to manage the incremental display based on the chosen answers. How you do this depends on your tools.

I populate my select dropdowns based on the current question's array of answers.  I have subscription (or watch) on the chosenAnswer property so that when a leaf answer is chosen (nextQuestion is null or undefined), I fire an event that includes the Answer object chosen as part of the event data.  Thus, I can record, or react to, the final chosen answer.

As an example, this is the self-referential template I used in knockout.js:

```
<script id="qaTmpl" type="text/html">
    <div class="col-md-12 clearfix leaders">
        <div>
            <label class="question pull-left">{{question}}</label>
            <span>
                <select class="pull-right" data-bind="disable: $root.editBuffer().valueId(),
                    options: answers, optionsText: 'answer', optionValue: 'answer', value: chosenAnswer, optionsCaption:'Choose...'"></select>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko if: $data && chosenAnswer&& chosenAnswer() && chosenAnswer().nextQuestion -->
    <!-- ko template: {name: 'qaTmpl', data: chosenAnswer().nextQuestion} --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

I hope you get the idea.  I wish I could be more specific, but a lot of the implementation details are specific to your framework and templating engine.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Code would definitely be helpful when you have a chance.

Comment: P.S., the AND/OR logic is implicit in the way you build the tree.

Comment: This is a valid solution and it's nice to be able to visualise the flow. But you may need to duplicate whole parts of the structure if your display logic is more complex. E.g if q10 depends on some answer from q2.

Comment: @Phil, you are correct. Repetitive sequences of questions are duplicated. I have manageable sets of questions. My largest, most complex Question Tree is just over 2000 nodes, which is not a problem for the browsers I need to support.

Comment: @BJSafdie Ah so are you generating the tree automatically in something like php or do you manage that structure manually? E.g. when you need to make changes to the logic

Comment: I use an ASP.NET Web API back-end that builds the tree based on a structure stored in SQL Server.  The analysts maintain the structure using Excel spreadsheets that we import into SQL Server right now, but I hope to write a simple maintenance page if we have time.

Comment: Then your base representation is in SQL and you're doing the complicated parsing and tree generation work serverside to make it easier for the js client. Working purely with just your js representation might be too much management work if things start getting complicated.  It depends on the complexity of the display logic.  I expect your SQL base representation does use explicit AND/OR logic right?

Comment: @Phil, we have a tight deadline, so we cheated.  We load the spreadsheets into a denormalized table that allows a question depth of up to 14 questions.  It's a kludge, but it serves our needs and then some. It is not horrible because we can predict the max question depth. It is tedious for the analysts to maintain, but I hope to fix that, as I said earlier.  The denormalized table is fast and plays to SQL strengths, whereas a more flexible structure would require more tables and/or self-referential tables that SQL does not like that well.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to keep your data and code separate, in this case that means the  values "val1", "val2" etc may be brought in via json, but the comparison should be coded in a js file. This can be done in a flexible way to account for the dynamic nature of your fields.

Trust me, using saved snippets of code to validate forms becomes a maintenance nightmare. Believe it or not I have actually done it early in my programming career, it is terrible.

Use a proper JSON parser instead of eval. If you can't encode what you need into something the a JSON parser will read then you don't want it in your JSON!

Is there any reason you couldn't just read in the data you are validating in this way?